# Compute a very big power using C++

Tags: c++, pow

I have a very big power

```
e.x. 5^4912

double x, y, z;
```

I used `z = pow( x, y )` function, but it gives me this result: [ 1.#INF ]

then, I tried to use a for loop that loops in 4912, but it gives me number like

```
-957893823
```

which seems rubbish

How can I solve a problem like that?

Comment: No native datatype can hold a number this large. You will need a big integer library with arbitrary precision.

Comment: The value in this example is of the order of 10^3433, which is way outside of the range of even double precision floating point: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E4912 - you'll need to use a BigNum library.

Comment: Check out [The GNU MP Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: why would you even want such a big number? There are only a very few set of applications that need this, and I'd be surprised if you are writing one of those applications and do not know of the existence of big-number libraries.

Comment: @KillianDS my money is on homework assignment.

Comment: i tried this in python 
add=1;
for i in range(0,5000):
 add=add+add*5;
 
print add
I got a gazillion long number.
you are surly out of range.

Comment: @Flexo: or something like project euler, in any case,there's a good chance that a `modpow` is the solution instead of a large number library (which is why I'm aksing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in data types (int, long and even double) can't hold the result of that calculation; so you can't use these.

Depending on the exact use case, I would recommend using a fitting library, e.g.:

- [Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)
- [GNU MP Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get large factorials and calculate large values use BigIntegers.
BigInteger in c++

---

Refer this link :http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/108176/